# How to Map Object / Class Property to Dictionary When Object Property And Dictionary Key Names Are Different?

Tags: c#, dictionary, mapping, automapper, bloomberg

I am calling Bloomberg Server API (for Stock Market Data) and getting Data back in a `Dictionary<string, object>` Where the `Key` to the dictionary is the `Field Name` on Bloomberg's side, and the object contains the data value from Bloomberg and can be `string`, `decimal`, `DateTime`, `boolean` etc.

After I get the Bloomberg Data, I need to populate my strong type entities  / classes with the values returned. Depending on what Field Names I send in my request to bloomberg, the returned Dictionary could have different key values. The problem I am having is, **the bloomberg field name and my .net entity's property names don't match**, so I am not sure I can do this mapping using `AutoMapper` or a similar library.

I also tried using a `Tuple<string,string,object>` where the 1st tuple item is the bloomberg field name, the 2nd tuple item is my entity's property name and the 3rd tuple item is the data value returned from bloomberg. That is not working out either (so far), so I am wondering if there is a simple straight-forward way of maintaining this bloombergfield<-->EntityProperty mapping and populate the Entity's value using the Bloomberg Data Value for the respective field. A Generic (i.e. using C# Generics) solution would be even better!

I have pasted below sample console app code so you can paste it and try it out. The 2 dictionaries, 1 for `stockdata` and other for `bonddata` have fake data, but you get the idea. I have also added comments below to re-iterate what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks!!

```
namespace MapBBFieldsToEntityProperties
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class Program
    {
        public class StockDataResult
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public decimal LastPrice { get; set; }
            public DateTime SettlementDate { get; set; }
            public decimal EPS { get; set; }

        }

        public class BondDataResult
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Issuer { get; set; }
            public decimal Duration { get; set; }
            public DateTime YieldToMaturity { get; set; }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Data Coming from Bloomberg. 
            // Dictionary Key is the Bloomberg Data Field Name. 
            // Dictionary Object is the Value returns and can be any .Net primitive Type

            // Sample Data returned for a Stock Query to Bloomberg
            Dictionary<string, object> dctBloombergStockData 
                = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                { "NAME", "IBM" },
                                {  "PX_LAST", 181.30f },
                                { "SETTLE_DT", "11/25/2013" } // This is Datetime value
                            };

            // Sample Data returned for a Bond Query to Bloomberg
            Dictionary<string, object> dctBloombergBondData = 
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                { "NAME", "IBM" },
                                { "ISSUE_ORG","IBM Corp" },
                                {  "DURATION", 4.430f },
                                { "YLD_TO_M", 6.456f }
                            };

            // This is my Stock Entity
            StockDataResult stockData = new StockDataResult();

            // This is my Bond Entity
            BondDataResult bondData = new BondDataResult();

            // PROBLEM STATEMENT:
            //
            // Need to somehow Map the Data returned from Bloomberg into the 
            // Corresponding Strong-typed Entity for that Data Type.
            // i.e. 
            // map dctBloombergStockData to stockData Entity instance as follows
            // 
            // dctBloombergStockData."NAME" Key  <--------> stockData.Name Property so that
            // dctBloombergStockData["NAME"] value of "IBM" can be assigned to stockData.Name
            // 
            // dctBloombergStockData."PX_LAST" Key  <--------> stockData.LastPrice Property so that
            // dctBloombergStockData["PX_LAST"] value 181.30f can be assigned to stockData.LastPrice value.
            // ....
            // .. you get the idea.
            // Similarly,
            // map dctBloombergBondData Data to bondData Entity instance as follows
            // 
            // dctBloombergBondData."NAME" Key  <--------> bondData.Name Property so that
            // dctBloombergBondData["NAME"] value of "IBM" can be assigned to bondData.Name property's value
            // 
            // dctBloombergBondData."ISSUE_ORG" Key  <--------> bondData.Issuer Property so that
            // dctBloombergBondData["ISSUE_ORG"] value 181.30f can be assigned to bondData.Issuer property's value.
            //
            // dctBloombergBondData."YLD_TO_M" Key  <--------> bondData.YieldToMaturity Property so that
            // dctBloombergBondData["YLD_TO_M"] value 181.30f can be assigned to bondData.YieldToMaturity property's value.                                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure quite a few improvements are possible, but this is one way of specifying a mapping and using that map.

```
class Program
{
    public class Mapper<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<TEntity, object>> _propertyMappers = new Dictionary<string, Action<TEntity, object>>();
        private Func<TEntity> _entityFactory;

        public Mapper<TEntity> ConstructUsing(Func<TEntity> entityFactory)
        {
            _entityFactory = entityFactory;
            return this;
        }

        public Mapper<TEntity> Map<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> memberExpression, string bloombergFieldName, Expression<Func<object, TProperty>> converter)
        {
            var converterInput = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "converterInput");
            var invokeConverter = Expression.Invoke(converter, converterInput);
            var assign = Expression.Assign(memberExpression.Body, invokeConverter);
            var mapAction = Expression.Lambda<Action<TEntity, object>>(
                assign, memberExpression.Parameters[0], converterInput).Compile();
            _propertyMappers[bloombergFieldName] = mapAction;
            return this;
        }

        public TEntity MapFrom(Dictionary<string, object> bloombergDict)
        {
            var instance = _entityFactory();
            foreach (var entry in bloombergDict)
            {
                _propertyMappers[entry.Key](instance, entry.Value);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public class StockDataResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal LastPrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime SettlementDate { get; set; }
        public decimal EPS { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var mapper = new Mapper<StockDataResult>()
            .ConstructUsing(() => new StockDataResult())
            .Map(x => x.Name, "NAME", p => (string)p)
            .Map(x => x.LastPrice, "PX_LAST", p => Convert.ToDecimal((float)p))
            .Map(x => x.SettlementDate, "SETTLE_DT", p => DateTime.ParseExact((string)p, "MM/dd/yyyy", null));


        var dctBloombergStockData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "NAME", "IBM" },
            {  "PX_LAST", 181.30f },
            { "SETTLE_DT", "11/25/2013" } // This is Datetime value
        };
        var myStockResult = mapper.MapFrom(dctBloombergStockData);

        Console.WriteLine(myStockResult.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(myStockResult.LastPrice);
        Console.WriteLine(myStockResult.SettlementDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is some nice code. I have made a couple of changes to it.

Comment: Thanks Alex & Max. I am going to test both of your answers over the weekend and let you know!

Comment: @Alex this works GREAT! Thank you. I tested it with BondData also. 1 question, I got an error if a field that's in the BloombergDataDictionary is not mapped to Entity. So I changed the MapFrom code as follows to check for key. Is this the right approach to fix that issue?                foreach (var entry in bloombergDict)
                {
                    if (_propertyMappers.ContainsKey(entry.Key)) 
                        _propertyMappers[entry.Key](instance, entry.Value);
                }

Comment: @Shiva If you really want to ignore fields that are present in the dictionary data that you receive, yes you could do that. I would suggest that you make it an explicit option that you check for. I.e. add a method to "Mapper" named "IgnoreUnmappedFields()", that sets a boolean flag you check for in the "MapFrom" method.

Comment: @Alex Thanks. Not sure I understand what you are suggesting. Maybe my question was vague. So the issue is, I send fields to bloomberg as List<string> = { "NAME", "PX_LAST", "SETTLE_DT"... etc}. and Bloomberg returns data that I convert to Dictionary<string, object> where key is the fieldname from the List<string> and object has value. So if the mapper code does not have a fieldname, I wanna ignore it. Are you saying that I should have the boolean flag, and then in the Mapper. MapFrom<.. method, do this check for ContainsKey() only if that boolean is set at the object level?

Comment: @Shiva I guess any solution specific to you use case is a decision you have to make since you know your use case and the involved data better than me. I usually try to prevent *silently* ignoring parts of data, which is why I suggested making it explicit (in the way you specify the map). And yes my suggestion boils down to how you described it in your comment.

Comment: HI all, I found this example as a what I Need for one small Project on which I working currently. I Need to achieve additional functionality and it's ablity to MAP data also to other direction. I'm not good with Expressions so could anyone give me example how to implement in mapper MAP method 4th Parameter as converter Expression as Output to Dictionary. Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 1):

As you have said your self you need a mapping table. You can create a static read only dictionary in you type that would map each key filed returned from Bloomberg to property in your strongly typed class.

Here is how I would do it.
PS: I used linqpad to test.
PPS: You can add as many mapper(s) to the dictionary as need be. You also need [fast-member](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) to run this code.

```
void Main()
{
  var dctBloombergStockData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "NAME", "IBM" },
            {  "PX_LAST", 181.30f },
            { "SETTLE_DT", "11/25/2013" } // This is Datetime value
        };
    StockDataResult.FromBloombergData(dctBloombergStockData);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
interface IMapper
{
    string PropertyName { get; }
    object Parse(object source);
}

class Mapper<T, TResult> : IMapper
{
    private Func<T, TResult> _parser;
    public Mapper(string propertyName, Func<T, TResult> parser)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        _parser = parser;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

    public TResult Parse(T source)
    {
        source.Dump();
        return _parser(source);
    }

    object IMapper.Parse(object source)
    {
        source.Dump();
        return Parse((T)source);
    }
}

public class StockDataResult
{
    private static TypeAccessor Accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(StockDataResult));

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, IMapper> Mappers = new Dictionary<string, IMapper>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase){
            { "NAME", new Mapper<string, string>("Name", a => a) },
            { "PX_LAST", new Mapper<float, decimal>("LastPrice", a => Convert.ToDecimal(a)) },
            { "SETTLE_DT", new Mapper<string, DateTime>("SettlementDate", a => DateTime.ParseExact(a, "MM/dd/yyyy", null)) }
        };

    protected StockDataResult()
    { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float LastPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime SettlementDate { get; set; }
    public decimal EPS { get; set; }

    public static StockDataResult FromBloombergData(Dictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        var result = new StockDataResult();
        IMapper mapper;
        foreach (var entry in state)
        {
            if(!Mappers.TryGetValue(entry.Key, out mapper))
            { continue; }
            Accessor[result, mapper.PropertyName.Dump()] = mapper.Parse(entry.Value);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a reference to the FastMember assembly from Google Code, also tried the Nuget Package. Still getting this error on the .Dump() statements while building the project. What am I missing? "'T' does not contain a definition for 'Dump' and no extension method 'Dump' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found".

Comment: I think your code will work too. Using FastMember in my codebase may involve a lot of paperwork to push through to get approval at my client site, so this may not be ideal solution. However, I do like your solution too and so I upvoted it. Thank you for writing the code.

Comment: Dump() method is part of linqpad. I use linqpad to do concept proof. You need to remove it since it is not available in vs.net.

Comment: Oh Ok. I commented out the two source.Dump statements and then removed the .Dump() from the assignment in this Line => Accessor[result, mapper.PropertyName] = mapper.Parse(entry.Value);   Now I am getting a CAST exception on above line from FastMember for the Price Value, i.e. When LastPrice gets assigned with 181.3. Will debug it later (since I have a solution now), but thought I'll let you know.

Comment: it is probebly because the value you get is not float. try to change float in mapper to object.  or see what value type is it.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
stockData.Name = dctBloombergStockData["NAME"];
stockData.LastPrice = dctBloombergStockData["PX_LAST"]
//and so on...
```

Comment: This won't work. I forgot to mention that the Bloomberg Dictionary Fields will be varying, depending on what I tell Bloomberg. i.e. 1 data result may have "Name" and "PX_LAST" while some other request might have "PX_LAST" and "SETTLE_DT". Hence I need a generic method / mapper.

Comment: Why not create some conditional statements and set the object properties based on the keys that are in the dictionary then?  How many different possibilities are there in the data that you're getting back?